# How to update a textview frequently with a spesific time delay?

Tags: android, loops, handler

I need to update a `TextView` frequently with a specific time delay in the android studio. The code is below. Thank you.

Edit: I also need to end the loop with a button click or with an "if" control.

```
//INFLATION CALCULATION !!!
/**
 * This method calculates Inflation value.
 */
public void calculateInflation() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            inflation = (cpi-cpiIni)/cpiIni*100;
            displayInflation();
            cpiIni = cpi;
        }
    }, delay*12);
}
```

Comment: keep a reference to the runnable, and handle it (adding, removing) in the context of the activity lifecycle. Also, you need to make the call to the post-delayed runnable recursive (otherwise you don't have the loop)

Comment: @Alessio it is the case. How can I make the call to the post-delayed runnable recursive? Thank you

Comment: do you know how to call a function recursively, right?

Comment: Do you mean the while loop? Yes.

Comment: no I don't mean the while loop, I mean how to call a function recursively, that is, a function that calls itself ... you can't use the while loop on Android UI thread, because you can't lock it or your app will get killed ... you need instead to call the function, which update your view, and then set the next call at a given time in future, after which you're back to square one (which naturally brings you to recursion)

Comment: Ahh i see it now. Yeah it worked for me. I called the "calculate" function in the function itself . Thank you for your help and detailed explanation. So it helped me to understand the problem with the while loop in the handler thread. Thanks indeed.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Call the same method inside the runnable in order to keep the loop going
2. Use a flag in order to be able to stop the loop: `shouldCalculate`

```
private boolean shouldCalculate = true; // set to false when you want to end the loop

public void calculateInflation() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (shouldCalculate) {
                inflation = (cpi-cpiIni)/cpiIni*100;
                displayInflation();
                cpiIni = cpi;
                calculateInflation();
            }
        }
    }, delay*12);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. This will do the trick. If you find any problem please let me know.

```
 public void calculateInflation() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        inflation = (cpi-cpiIni)/cpiIni*100;
        displayInflation();
        cpiIni = cpi;
        if(shouldRepeat)
           calculateInflation();
        }
    }, delay*12);
}
```

And second approach can be CountDownTimer. Make a method as shown in below code

```
 public void timerTask(final int loopTime){
     //Loop time is the actual time for repeatation
    new CountDownTimer(loopTime, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //this tells you one second is passed
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //here on time finish you need to define your task
            inflation = (cpi-cpiIni)/cpiIni*100;
            displayInflation();
            cpiIni = cpi;
            //call the same method again for looping
            timerTask(loopTime);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: The first approach is a very interesting approach I like it but how can I end the loop. Is it possible to add if condition in the handler? Like if a switch is on keep looping else stop looping? Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, you can use boolean as a switch.Before repeating it should check the switch and you can update the switch according to your need

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        inflation = (cpi-cpiIni)/cpiIni*100;
        displayInflation();
        cpiIni = cpi;

        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }

};


  public void startTimer() {
    //timer
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

}

public void stopTimer() {
    //timer stops
    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
    //timer ends
}
```

make a reference of runnable thread , start it using `startTimer()` and remove thread using `stopTimer()` as you said on a button click or up on a specific conditions .Also you can change the postDelayed milliseconds as ur wish

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way. Here `updateRunnable` calls itself with delay. Make `updateRunnable` as global variable to access from anywhere.

```
Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        inflation = (cpi-cpiIni)/cpiIni*100;
        displayInflation();
        cpiIni = cpi;

        handler.postDelayed(this, UPDATE_TIME);
    }
};
```

Start handler. Here we start handler immediately without delay.

```
handler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 0)
```

Stop handler

```
handler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)
```

By the way don't forget to stop handler on `onDestroy()`

Comment: Happy to help you.